# Navigating to another component in hybrid Angular

Tags: angular, angular-hybrid

I cannot figure out how can I navigate to another page/component with hybrid Angular.

In Angular 2 we use Router and something like:

```
this.router.navigate(['/items']);
```

In hybrid Angular I use hybrid routing with:

```
import { UIRouterUpgradeModule, NgHybridStateDeclaration } from '@uirouter/angular-hybrid';
```

How can I navigate from within typescript to another page/component with hybrid Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually using the uirouter. It is the hybrid version but still it is the uirouter. 
For the equivalent of this.router.navigate you can use:

```js
this.uirouter.stateService.go('items');
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this repository [github.com/Zadvornyi/angular-hybrid-webpack](https://github.com/Zadvornyi/angular-hybrid-webpack), where implement @uirouter/angular-hybrid router. After implementing you can use
standard method:

- Angular JS `$state.go('some state')`
- Angular 2+ `this.$stage.go('some stage')`